# How can I determine the calling view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a **drawer** with two sections.. therefore I implemented a **delegate pattern** to access a embedded **tableView** inside of my **container**.

```
class Drawer: UIViewController, DrawerTableViewDelegate {

    var drawerVC : DrawerTableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()      
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "tableViewSegue" {
        self.drawerVC = (segue.destination as! DrawerTableView
        self.drawerVC!.delegate = self
        }

    }
```

In my **DrawerTableView** class is the **delegate** implemented and also some code to access the rows in the **tableView**:

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate : MenuTableViewControllerDelegate?
//tableview delegate
```

The **drawer** gets called in two scenes in the same way:

```
@objc func didTapRowInDrawer(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard let drawerVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerCtrl") as? Drawer else { return }
        drawerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        drawerVC.transitioningDelegate = self
present(drawerVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Can I determine the calling **ViewController** of my **drawer**?

I thought of something like

```
if segue.source is VC {
   //do something
} else if segue.source is VC2 {
  // do something else
}
```

in ***Drawer::prepare***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, it looks like the Drawer was presented as a Modal. The viewController which presented a Modal is stored in `presentingViewController` variable. You can use the below code in the `DrawerViewController` to determine which `ViewController` had presented the Drawer.

```
if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController {
    if presentingVC.isKind(of: VC1.self) {
          //do something
    } else if presentingVC.isKind(of: VC2.self) {
         // do something else
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I have to add the code exactly in my **Drawer** class? In the **prepareForSegue** method?

Comment: `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` should work for your case.

Comment: I already tried to put in in there but it does not execute the **if else** statement. I placed your code inside of **if segue.identifier == "tableViewSegue" { ...**

Comment: Do you mean `if segue.identifier == "tableViewSegue" ` is failing or is `if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController` failing?

Comment: **presentingVC** is failing.

Comment: If the `Drawer` is presented as a Modal then this property will hold a weak reference of the ViewController on which this was presented.

Comment: Another simple thing that you can do is to add a weak variable of type UIViewController to `Drawer`. assign this property to the viewcontroller which is presenting `Drawer` and use this property to check from which viewController your Drawer was presented.

Comment: So in my **Drawer** class: ***weak var ctrl : UIViewController?*** and in the **didTapRowInDrawer** method something like ***drawerVC.vtrl = self*** ?

Comment: I got your point. When I set a breakpoint and check the vc it shows me the correct **presentigVC** but skips the if else statement

Comment: `drawerVC.vtrl = self ` is correct. this is be done prior to presenting drawer as a modal. So the above code in your prepareForSegue changes as below:

Comment: `if let presentingVC = self. vtrl {
    if presentingVC.isKind(of: VC1.self) {
          //do something
    } else if presentingVC.isKind(of: VC2.self) {
         // do something else
    }
 }`

Comment: Happy to help :)